# Mongoose - can't insert subDocuments of a Dictionary Type

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have a Mongoose schema for the document `Company`, that has several fields. One of these (`documents_banks`) is a "free" field, of dictionary type, because I don't know the names of the keys in advance.
The problem is that, when I save the document (`company.save()`) even if the resulting saved document has the new sub_docs, in the DB no new sub_docs are actually saved.

```
var Company = new Schema({
  banks: [{ type: String }], // array of Strings
  documents_banks: {} // free field
});
```

Even if `documents_banks` is not restricted by the Schema, it will have this structure (in my mind):

```
{
  "bank_id1": {
    "doc_type1": {
      "url": { "type": "String" },
      "custom_name": { "type": "String" }
    },
    "doc_type2": {
      "url": { "type": "String" },
      "custom_name": { "type": "String" }
    }
  },
  "bank_id2": {
    "doc_type1": {
      "url": { "type": "String" },
      "custom_name": { "type": "String" }
    }
  }
}
```

But I don't know in advance names of keys `bank_id` neither `doc_type`, so I used the Dictionary type (`documents_banks:{}`).

Now, this below is the function I use to save new sub_docs in `documents_banks`. The same logic I always use to save new sub_docs..  Anyway this time, it seems saved, but it's not.

```
function addBankDocument(company_id, bank_id, doc_type, url, custom_name) {
  // retrieve the company document
  Company.findById(company_id)
    .then(function(company) {

      // create empty sub_docs if needed
      if (!company.documents_banks) {
        company.documents_banks = {};
      }
      if (!company.documents_banks[bank_id]) {
        company.documents_banks[bank_id] = {};
      }

      // add the new sub_doc
      company.documents_bank[bank_id][doc_type] = {
        "url": url,
        "custom_name": custom_name
      };
      return company.save();
    })
    .then(function(saved_company) {
      // I try to check if the new obj has been saved
      console.log(saved_company.documents_bank[bank_id][doc_type]);
      // and it actually prints the new obj!!
    });
}
```

The `saved_company` returned by the `.save()` actually has the new sub_docs, but if I check the DB there is not the new sub_doc! I can save just the first one, all the others are not stored.

So, the console.log() always print the new sub_docs, but actually in the DataBase, just the first sub_doc is saved, not the others. So at the end, `saved_company` always has 1 sub_doc, the first one.

It seems very strange to me, since `saved_company` has the new sub_docs. What can be happened?

This below is a real extract from by DB, and it will contains forever just the sub_doc `"doc_bank@1573807781414"`, others will be not present in the DB.

```
{
  "_id": "5c6eaf8efdc21500146e289c", // company_id
  "banks": [ "MPS" ],
  "documents_banks": {
    "5c5ac3e025acd98596021a9a": // bank_id
    {
      "doc_bank@1573807781414": // doc_type
      {
        "url": "http://...",
        "custom_name": "file1"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Versions:

```
$ npm -v
6.4.1

$ npm show mongoose version
5.7.11

$ node -v
v8.16.0
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that, since mongoose doesn't know the exact model of the subdoc, it can't know when it changes. So I have to use `markModified` to notify changes of the "free field" (also known as dictionary or MixedType) with this:

```js
    company_doc.documents_banks["bank_id2"]["doc_type3"] = obj; // modify
    company_doc.markModified('documents_banks'); // <--- notify changes
    company_doc.save(); // save changes
```

As I understood, `markModified` force the model to 'update' that field during the save().